# Multi-Level dependency Injection with Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, dependencies, constructor-injection

I am trying to understand under the hood Angular framework dependency Injection resolution.

I have a service called ***Car*** which has a function called **fetchCarDetails(cylinderQuant, tyretype)** dependent on ***Engine*** (horsepower) and ***Tyre*** (brands) classes.

The Car class is then manually resolved in ***User-demo*** component and params for Engine and tyre class are provided there.

**1) Car Class**

```
import { Injectable, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { EngineService } from '../services/engine.service';
import { TyreService } from '../services/tyre.service';

@Injectable()
export class CarService {
constructor(public engine: EngineService, public tyre: TyreService) { }

fetchCarDetails(cylinderQuant, tyretype) {
this.engine.cylinders = cylinderQuant;
this.tyre.tyrebrand = tyretype;
return `car has ` + `${this.engine.cylinders} and ${this.tyre.tyrebrand} as a whole.`;
}
```

**2) Engine**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class EngineService {
 cylinders;
 constructor(cylindernum) {
  this.cylinders = cylindernum;
}
 }
}
```

**3) Tyre**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class TyreService {
tyrebrand: any;
constructor(tyre) {
this.tyrebrand = tyre;
 }
}
```

**4)  User-Demo**

```
import { Component, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { CarService } from '../services/car.service';
import { EngineService } from '../services/engine.service';
import { TyreService } from '../services/tyre.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-demo',
  templateUrl: './user-demo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-demo.component.css']
})
export class UserDemoComponent {

  carService: CarService;
  EngineService: CarService;
  TyreService: CarService;
  carDemo: string;
  constructor() {

  const injector: any = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([CarService, EngineService, TyreService]);
    this.carDemo = injector.get(CarService);
  }

  CarDetails(): void {

    this.carDemo = this.carService.fetchCarDetails(12, 'ceat');

    console.log('Details are : ', this.carDemo);
  }   
 }
}
```

Getting the below error at run-time.. Will welcome any help/suggestion here.

***Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'EngineService'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'EngineService' is decorated with Injectable.
Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'EngineService'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'EngineService' is decorated with Injectable.***

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR3Uj.png)

Comment: correction on dependencies... carService: CarService;
     EngineService: EngineService;
     TyreService: TyreService;

Comment: Only other injectables (i.e. services) can be injected in services. `cylindernum` is not a service. `tyre` is not a service. Not **everything** needs to be a service. Data classes and primitives are typically not services. A car service wold typically create Car instances by delegating to TyreService to create 4 tyres, to EngineService to create an engine, and then create and return a Car by assembling all the pieces. And services are meant to be injected. Don't use reflective injector to get a service. Inject it in the component constructor.

Comment: @JBNizet : Yeah.. I don't intend to use reflective injector at later stage.. either Ngmodule or component provider will do. but can't I make it run with reflective injector.?  cylindernum and tyre are params

Comment: Again, only services can be injected. `cylindernum` is not a service. How could Angular know what to pass as the `cylindernum` value when creating an EngineService?

Comment: @JBNizet: agree there.. so I moved the `cylindernum` and `tyre` params in to setGet functions in respective classes and used `fetchCarDetails()` of car class which returned me assembled car connecting `Engine` and `Tyre` class.

Comment: Since I didn't make use of providers array in the Car service class. How could its `constructor(public engine: EngineService, public tyre: TyreService)` injected/make us of `EngineService` & `TyreService` in assembling/instantiating  the car? could you suggest here ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection